# ScrollView not working even tho it works on other components

Tags: react-native

Hello guys i have been working on the ubereats clone and while using scrollView it doesnt work ,
i used it on other components the same way and it worked fine but here it doesnt !! ?

````
const MenuItem=()=>{
    return(
      <ScrollView showsVerticalScrollIndicator={false}>    
        <View style={{paddingHorizontal:10}} >
           
        {Menu.map((food,index)=>(   
            <View style={{paddingLeft:20,flexDirection:"row",marginTop:30,borderTopWidth:1,borderTopColor:"lightgray",paddingTop:10}} key={index} >
            <View style={{justifyContent:"center"}}><BouncyCheckbox 
            iconStyle={{borderColor: "gray",borderRadius:0}}
            fillColor='green'
            /></View>
            <View style={{width:220,marginLeft:10}}>
              <Text style={{fontSize:20,fontWeight:"700"}}>{food.title}</Text>
              <Text > {food.description}</Text>
              <View style={{marginTop:8}}>
              <Text style={{fontSize:17,fontWeight:"500"}}>{food.price}</Text></View>
            </View>
            <View style={{marginLeft:18}}>
                  <Image source={{uri:food.image}} style={{width:80,height:80,borderRadius:30}}/> 
            </View>    
        </View>   
        ))}
       </View>
       </ScrollView>
    )
}```

i used flex 1 on the view outside the map function and it didnt fix it
````

Comment: Try contentContainerStyle={{flex: 1}}

Comment: Put your View as a parent for scrollView;

Answer (score 0):

Remove the View above the ScrollView.

You try to set one child for the scrollView it’s the View component and the View component have array map.

Remove the View component to keep array map child for ScrollView

Comment: i tried it and still doesnt wanna scroll